# A question regarding linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem in a textbook goes as follows: Show that if S is a linearly independent set of vectors, then so is every nonempty subset of S.

Is it acceptable to say that since every vector in S is linearly independent, then any vectors that make up a subset of S will also be linearly independent? Or is that logically incorrect?

Comment: Be careful with what you mean by 'every vector is linearly independent'. It's **always** the case that $\{\mathbf v\}$ is a linearly independent set for all $0 \neq \mathbf v \in V$... I would rather argue that if $S' \subseteq S$ was a linearly dependent set, then viewing the vectors in $S'$ as elements of $S$, we'd have that $S$ was linearly dependent - contradiction.

Comment: And the empty set is linearly independent too.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: "every vector in $S$ is linearly independent" makes no sense.

Comment: It is important that you realise that linear independence is a property _only_ of sets (or families) of vectors, not of individual vectors. It is for this reason that you argument is invalid. The danger is in reasoning in the opposite direction: the fact that every vector belongs to a linearly independent subset does not imply that the whole set of vectors is linearly independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linearly independent according to the formal definition means, if $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ then $S$ is linearly independent when: supposing \begin{equation}\mathbf{0}=a_1s_1+\cdots+a_ns_n, \quad (1)\end{equation} we must have \begin{equation}a_1=\cdots=a_n=0. \quad (2)\end{equation}

Now suppose to the contrary, that there is some subset $\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ which is linearly dependent, that is, we can find $b_1,\ldots,b_k$, not all zero, so that $\mathbf{0}=b_1s_1+\cdots+b_ks_k$. But then $\mathbf{0}=b_1s_1+\cdots+b_ks_k+a_ls_l+\cdots+a_ns_n$ contradicting $(2)$.

So we must have $\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use logic here, you can also prove it by contradiction.

Let $S=\{v_i\}_{1=1}^n$, and let $0<m<n$. Then every non empty subset of $S$ is $S_m=\{v_i\}_{1=1}^m$, up to relabeling of the elements of $S$. Then, if $S_m$ was linearly independent, there would exist $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m\}$, not all zero scalars such that $\Sigma_{i=1}^m a_iv_i=\vec 0$. Extending the set of $a_i$ with $\{a_{m+1},... ,a_n\}$ all zero yields that $\Sigma_{i=1}^n a_iv_i=\vec 0$, which contradicts the linear independence of $S$.

So $S_m$ are linearly independent for any $m$.

Comment: By using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction you do in fact make use of logic (just as a btw)

Comment: @christiaan-hattingh Yes, every proof is logic. I think that in the context of the question, it is clear I was talking about the heuristic kind of proof that was suggested, and not the whole discipline of logical thinking.